# Raspberry Pi3 is not working without internet connection

Tags: raspbian, linux

My Raspberry Pi3 won't boot unless I connect it with an Ethernet cable to my router or to my laptop. What if I wanted to use the raspberry Pi in a place that has no internet connection? Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: A freshly Debian or eq will boot without network. Have you made any changes or is running another OS? Your question is lacking facts and data.

Comment: I haven't made any changes with it. The os is RASPBIAN STRETCH WITH DESKTOP.

Comment: No need to scream!

Comment: HaHaHaHaHa I didn't mean to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option "Wait for Network on Boot", I suspect this could be the culprit.
To change it simply type

`sudo raspi-config`

in a terminal and select "Boot Options" > "Wait for Network on Boot"